# the html_strip character filter in ElasticSearch replaces tags with newlines?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm testing some custom filters for ElasticSearch and because I'm obsessive I decided to test the standard html_strip character filter too, to confirm that I know how it works.

So it seems that I *don't* know how it works, because I assumed that it would strip all HTML and replace it with nothing, but it seems to do different things for different tags, e.g. p (and div) tags replace with newline:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test-analysis/_analyze?tokenizer=keyword&char_filters=html_strip&pretty=1' -d 'Oh <p class="stuff">pickles</p>!'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
  "token" : "Oh \npickles\n!",
  "start_offset" : 0,
  "end_offset" : 32,
  "type" : "word",
  "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

The strong tag and link replace with nothing:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test-analysis/_analyze?tokenizer=keyword&char_filters=html_strip&pretty=1' -d 'Oh <a href="stuff">pickles</a>!'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
   "token" : "Oh pickles!",
   "start_offset" : 0,
   "end_offset" : 31,
   "type" : "word",
   "position" : 1
 } ]
}
```

Of course I can add ANOTHER filter that removes newlines, but is there any documentation about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that HTML block tags such as `<div>`, `<p>`, etc are replaced by newline characters and HTML inline tags such as `a`, `strong`, etc are simply eliminated.

This is confirmed when looking at the source code for [`HTMLStripCharFilter.java`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/lucene-solr/master/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/charfilter/HTMLStripCharFilter.java) in the Lucene source code. At some point in that class, we can see a few constants like these, which speak for themselves:

```
  private static final char BLOCK_LEVEL_START_TAG_REPLACEMENT = '\n';
  private static final char BLOCK_LEVEL_END_TAG_REPLACEMENT = '\n';
  private static final char BR_START_TAG_REPLACEMENT = '\n';
  private static final char BR_END_TAG_REPLACEMENT = '\n';
  private static final char SCRIPT_REPLACEMENT = '\n';
  private static final char STYLE_REPLACEMENT = '\n';
  private static final char REPLACEMENT_CHARACTER = '\uFFFD';
```

The idea is to more or less reproduce the same text paragraphs as would be rendered in the browser screen.

Comment: Thanks so much for the link! This makes sense, it's just weird given the filter name.